# Scala, Kryo serialization and versioning

Tags: scala, serialization, versioning, kryo

I've recently been looking into Kryo for serialization of long lived journal events. I am trying to deserialize an event serialized in one version as a newer version. For example I've serialized a case class such as Foo(a:Int). When I deserialized it into the newer version Foo(a:Int, b:Option[String] = None) where a default is specified for the new field added.  I find that it does deserialize, however, it will populate the new field with a null. Is there a way to specify to Kryo that there is a new field and that it should be defaulted. In this case, I am using CompatibleFieldSerializer as the default serializer which from what I understand should allow for both forward and backward compatibility.